# How to append text to a file in PHP from the web interface?

Tags: php

I have a text file.

name.txt (contains)

```
Sean:”allen”
Peter:”fletcher”
Jake:”wilson”
```

**This is the code:**

```
<?php

// set file to read
$filename = “name.txt”;
$newdata = $_POST['newd'];

if ($newdata != '') {
    // open file 
    $fw = fopen($filename, 'w') or die('Could not open file!');

    // write to file
    // added stripslashes to $newdata

    $fb = fwrite($fw,stripslashes($newdata)) or die('Could not write to file');
    // close file
    fclose($fw);
}

// print file contents

echo "<h3>DEV: Add/Remove Configurations</h3>
    <form action='$_SERVER[php_self]' method= 'post' >
    <textarea name='newd' cols='90%' rows='50'> $data </textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='Change'>
    </form>";
?>
```

How do I fix the PHP script to append text to the name.txt if I want to add 
a line (Tommy: “Johnson”). Right now the script overwrite the file name.txt

**=== Output should be ===** 
name.txt (should contains)

```
  Sean:”allen”
  Peter:”fletcher”
  Jake:”wilson”
  Tommy: “Johnson”)
```

Please Advise! Thx

Comment: By the look of your double quotes, it looks like to are using Word or something similar to write code Get yourself a decent free text editor like `notepad++`

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the file incorrectly, if you want to append data to the end of the file use the `a+` parameter. `a+` = append and if the file does not exist create it

```
<?php

// set file to read
$filename = “name.txt”;
$newdata = $_POST['newd'];

if ($newdata != '') {
    // open file 
    //$fw = fopen($filename, 'w') or die('Could not open file!');
    $fw = fopen($filename, 'a+') or die('Could not open file!');

    // write to file
    // added stripslashes to $newdata

    $fb = fwrite($fw,stripslashes($newdata)) or die('Could not write to file');
    // close file
    fclose($fw);
}

// print file contents

echo "<h3>DEV: Add/Remove Configurations</h3>
    <form action='$_SERVER[php_self]' method= 'post' >
    <textarea name='newd' cols='90%' rows='50'> $data </textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='Change'>
    </form>";
?>
```